# How To Change ASP.NET Core Web App Navbar Background Color

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to edit the background color of the navbar of my dotnet core razor page web app.
Original, it is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
```

I tried to create a `bg-blue` in the `bootstrap.css` and change `bg-white` above to `bg-blue` but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong? Thank you for help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that sometimes the bootstrap classes dont work for me so I suggest trying normal css to color the background of the navbar.

```
style="background-color: blue"
```

Try adding the above as a parameter in the nav element

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am using ASP.net Core with .net Core 5. Go to the file called NavMenu.js in the render method it will say:

```
<header>
 <Navbar classname="..." light>
```

Remove the light attribute and it will use your css values.

Fixed it is:

```
<header>
 <Navbar classname="...">
```

Answer (score 0):

For styling any kind of box, text, header, footer etc You need to use `style` attribute if you bootstrap class don't work. yo can implement as follow:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3" style="background-color: green">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `"bg-white"` and add `style="background-color: blue"`

So your `"<nav>"` element looks as follows

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light border-bottom box-shadow mb-3" style="background-color: blue">
```